# RichEditableText SelectionColor

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark, richeditabletext

I'm new to flex, actually I'm reading a simple tutorial about Flex 4 (I'm using flash builder 4.5) this is the [tutorial](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/gumbo/flex_4_tutorials.pdf).

I added a RichEditableText and then I should specify the property *selectionColor*, but when I add it to the source code, the IDE give me an error like this property do not exist.

```
 <s:RichEditableText x="179" y="95" text="hello" fontSize="24" fontWeight="bold" color="#E52222" selectionColor="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is slightly different now. It's `focusedTextSelectionColor` There's also an `unfocusedTextSelectionColor`. The article you are reading is for a Flex Gumbo Pre-Release. That's basically a beta version of 4.0 and now we're on the 4.5 SDK so there are slight differences. Here is a good tutorial from FlexExamples: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/11/07/setting-the-selection-highlight-color-on-a-spark-richeditabletext-control-in-flex-4/